# Highchart sankey- Show multiple entries having same name independently

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

I have a requirement that in case of an example like

I want the two r1s to appear independently on their respective axis 
I.e

I want something like

```
l1 - r1 

l3 - r1 

l2 - r2

r1 - r3
```

i.e the 2 r1s should exist independently on the correct sides I.e the ‘from and’to’sides depending on their position in the array of data say having keys [‘from’ ,’to’, ‘weight’

I do not want

```
L1 - r1 - r3
```

Comment: [
[l1 , r1 ],
[l2 , r2 ],
[l3, r1],
[r1 , r3 ],
]

Comment: The above is how the data is in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use distinct values in the `data` object, and then use the `nodes` object to make their names (and optionally colors) the same.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
  },

  series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight', 'id'],
    data: [{
        from: 'L1',
        to: 'R1',
        weight: 5
      },
      {
        from: 'L3',
        to: 'R1',
        weight: 1
      },
      {
        from: 'L2',
        to: 'R2',
        weight: 1
      },
      {
        from: 'L4',
        to: 'R3',
        weight: 1
      },
    ],
    nodes: [{
        id: 'L4',
        name: 'R1',
        color: '#000'
      },
      {
        id: 'R1',
        name: 'R1',
        color: '#000'
      }
    ],
    type: 'sankey',
    name: 'Sankey demo series'
  }]

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kLx2n7mz/12/

Note, you wouldn't need to include `id:'R1'` in the `nodes` object if you didn't want to assure they have the same color.

Comment: This is a very smart answer and way of presenting it. Thank you